# Android: ContentObserver not working in android 4.3

Tags: java, android

ContentObserver works fine in android 4.0.4 where it detects changes made in settings app. But when under android 4.3 it doesnt detect the change and the service doesnt start

SettingsContentObserver.java:

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{

private Context context;


public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler, Context applicationContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(handler);
    this.context = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
{
    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
{
    super.onChange(selfChange);

  System.out.println("Change detected");
  Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
  context.startService(i);
}



}
```

MyService.java:

```
public void onCreate() {
 SettingsContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver = new SettingsContentObserver(new Handler(), getApplicationContext());
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mSettingsContentObserver);
    System.out.println("Observer registered");
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            System.out.println("Service works");

}
```

Thanks,
Sahil

Comment: What settings are you looking for? In Android 4.2, many moved over to Settings.Global (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) so it might be worth listening to the content uri provided there as well.

Comment: Yes the data setting was moved from secure to global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these settings have been moved to [`Settings.Global`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) as of Android 4.2 - so listen to the content Uri provided there as well.