# Contacts Update to DB Not working with ContentObserver

Tags: android, contacts, contentobserver

I am working with an Android application which shows the list of contacts in the phone like Whats-app. I am successful with getting the contacts to the Application database. When I try to update my DB when a contact is newly added/edited/deleted using Content Observer, I mainly face two problems
1. When Calls ,

```
String contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

I am getting wrong name. eg:- I edited Samuel's Contact no but checking the above code getting David's name.

2. when I try to get contact number by using the code,

   ```
    contactNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
   ```

   I am getting error

   ```
   E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 402 rows, 41 columns.

   03-01 17:16:56.546 3660-3660/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
   ```

   Please Anybody help me to find the solution.
   Here is my Code

   ```
   public class ContactObserver extends ContentObserver {
   Intent i;
   private static final String TAG = "ObserverReceiver";

   private Context context;
   BaseActivity mBaseActivity;

   public ContactObserver(Handler handler, BaseActivity context) {
   super(handler);
   this.mBaseActivity = context;
   this.context = context;
   }

   public ContactObserver() {
   super(null);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
   return true;
   }
    @Override
   public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
   super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
   if (!selfChange) {
       try {

           ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
           Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
           Log.d(TAG, "Observer has been started..");


           // Contacts Cursor
           final Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

           // Check which contact is added or updated
           if (cur != null) {
               while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                   // Get contact added/updated timestamp but CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
                   // Get new/updated contact detail here

                   final String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                   final String contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                   String contactNumber = null;
                   if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                       try {
                           contactNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                       } catch (Exception e) {

                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }

                   String finalContactNumber = contactNumber;
                   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           List<Contacts> sContacts = ContactDatabase
                                   .getDatabase(context)
                                   .contactsDao()
                                   .getBySystemid(id);
                           Log.i("Contacts1+", new Gson().toJson(sContacts));
                           if (sContacts.size() > 0) {

                               for (Contacts mContacts : sContacts) {
                                   String phone = finalContactNumber;
                                   if (phone == null) {
                                       phone = mContacts.getPhone();
                                   }
                                   Log.i("Contacts1+", contactName + " : " + phone);
                                   if (phone != null && phone.length() > 0) {
                                       phone = phone.replace(" ", "");
                                   }
                                   while (String.valueOf(phone.charAt(0)).equals("0")) {
                                       String num = "";
                                       for (int i = 1; i < phone.length(); i++) {
                                           num = num + phone.charAt(i);
                                       }
                                       phone = num;
                                   }
                                   if (phone.length() == 10) {
                                       phone = getSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.COUNTRY_CODE) + phone;
                                   }
                                   if ((mContacts.getName() != contactName || mContacts.getPhone() != phone)) {
                                       mContacts.setName(contactName);
                                       if (!mContacts.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase(phone)) {
                                           mContacts.setPhone(phone);
                                           mContacts.setIslisted("false");
                                       }
                                       if (mContacts.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase(phone) || mContacts.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(contactName)) {
                                           ContactDatabase.getDatabase(context)
                                                   .contactsDao()
                                                   .update(mContacts);
                                           cur.close();

                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                           } else {
                               Contacts mContacts = new Contacts();
                               String contactNumber = null;
                               try {
                                   contactNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                   if (contactNumber != null && contactNumber.length() > 0) {
                                       contactNumber = contactNumber.replace(" ", "");
                                       contactNumber = contactNumber.replace("-", "");
                                   }
                                   while (String.valueOf(contactNumber.charAt(0)).equals("0")) {
                                       String num = "";
                                       for (int i = 1; i < contactNumber.length(); i++) {
                                           num = num + contactNumber.charAt(i);
                                       }
                                       contactNumber = num;
                                   }
                                   if (contactNumber.length() == 10) {
                                       contactNumber = getSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.COUNTRY_CODE) + contactNumber;
                                   }
                                   String contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                   mContacts.setPhone(contactNumber);
                                   mContacts.setName(contactName);
                                   mContacts.setSystemid(id);
                                   mContacts.setIslisted("false");
                                   List<Contacts> cContacts = ContactDatabase
                                           .getDatabase(context)
                                           .contactsDao()
                                           .getbyPhone(contactNumber);
                                   if (cContacts.size() == 0) {
                                       ContactDatabase.getDatabase(context)
                                               .contactsDao()
                                               .insert(mContacts);
                                   }
                               } catch (Exception e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                           }
                           i = new Intent(context, ContactSynchService.class);
                           context.startService(i);
                           cur.close();

                       }
                   });
                   thread.start();
               }

           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   }



       public String getSharedPreference(String key) {
           SharedPreferences prefs = mBaseActivity.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.SHARED_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
           return prefs.getString(key, "DEFAULT");
       }


   }
   ```

I tried these links, but none of them could give a solution.

[ContentObserver for contact update manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244140/contentobserver-for-contact-update-manually)

[ContentObserver not working in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198375/contentobserver-not-working-in-android)

[Android: ContentObserver not working in android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343773/android-contentobserver-not-working-in-android-4-3)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance